# Whats a Shadow Password?

Tags: 12.10, wubi, helpfile

I liked the Ubuntu 12.10, so i Downloaded it and and installed via WUBI, then it told me to restart my PC to complete the installation. After i restarted and selected Ubuntu in the OS selection; for a few seconds a blank screen came and then it showed Shadow Password is on; then a blank screen for a few more seconds; then a whole lot of code-like characters came and it just won't boot up. I just wanna use 12.10 nothing else, i have Vista Business installed on the C:/ Drive, And Ubuntu is installed on the F:/ Drive (F:/ubuntu).

Comment: Details of your computer would help... Brand, model, graphics card(s). Most likely it's a graphics card issue. i.e. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: I doubt that "shadow password" has anything to do with your problem, and I think this question will focus on that. Maybe reword the whole thing into your real problem: you can't boot, instead of the more or less 'random' thing you picked out as the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Shadow passwords are an enhancement to login security on Unix systems. Traditionally, passwords are kept in encrypted form in a world-readable table ( `/etc/passwd` ). To test a password, a program encrypts the given password with the same "key" (salt) that was used to encrypt the password stored in the `/etc/passwd` file (the salt is always given as the first two characters of the password). Because the encrypted passwords are not "decryptable", authentication takes place by comparison. If the `/etc/passwd/` file password matches the encrypted login password, the user is granted access.

More reading [HERE](http://kb.iu.edu/data/aezz.html)